# how to exclude an applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

I have two applicationContext file, one for development and one for testing. They are called as `applicationContext.xml` and `applicationContextTest.xm`l.

But when I run the JUnit test, I find `applicationContext.xml` get loaded as well. How can I exclude `applicationContext.xml` from loading while running JUnit?

Comment: Could you put the annotations above your test case?

Comment: I find the cause, the parent class of my class is loading applicationContext.xml